# Dataflow discarding massive amount of events due to Window object or inner processing

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam

Been recently developing a Dataflow consumer which read from a PubSub subscription and outputs to Parquet files the combination of all those objects grouped within the same window.

While I was doing testing of this without  a huge load everything seemed to work fine.

However, after performing some heavy testing I can see that **from 1.000.000 events** sent to that PubSub queue, **only 1000 make it to Parquet**!

According to multiple wall times across different stages, the one which parses the events prior applying the window seems to last 58 minutes. The last **stage which writes to Parquet files lasts 1h and 32 minutes**.

I will show now the most relevant parts of the code within, hope you can shed some light if its due to the logic that comes before the Window object definition or if it's the Window object iself.

```
pipeline
        .apply("Reading PubSub Events",
            PubsubIO.readMessagesWithAttributes()
                .fromSubscription(options.getSubscription()))
        .apply("Map to AvroSchemaRecord (GenericRecord)",
            ParDo.of(new PubsubMessageToGenericRecord()))
        .setCoder(AvroCoder.of(AVRO_SCHEMA))
        .apply("15m window",
            Window.<GenericRecord>into(FixedWindows.of(Duration.standardMinutes(15)))
                .triggering(AfterProcessingTime
                    .pastFirstElementInPane()
                    .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
                .withAllowedLateness(Duration.ZERO)
                .accumulatingFiredPanes()
        )
```

Also note that I'm running Beam 2.9.0.

Could the logic inside the second stage be too heavy so that messages arrive too late and get discarded in the Window? The logic basically consists reading the payload, parsing into a POJO (reading inner Map attributes, filtering and such)

However, if I sent a million events to PubSub, all those million events make it till the Parquet write to file stage, but then those Parquet files don't contain all those events, just partially. Does that make sense?

I would need the trigger to consume all those events independently of the delay.

Comment: Are you doing something after the Window? You'd need a GroupByKey or Combine to make use of the Window. https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#windowing

Answer (score 1):

Citing from an answer on the Apache Beam mailing list:

This is an unfortunate usability problem with triggers where you can accidentally close the window and drop all data. I think instead, you probably want this trigger:

```
Repeatedly.forever(
    AfterProcessingTime
                .pastFirstElementInPane()
                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
```

The way I recommend to express this trigger is:

```
AfterWatermark.pastEndOfWindow().withEarlyFirings(
    AfterProcessingTime
                .pastFirstElementInPane()
                .plusDelayOf(Duration.standardSeconds(1)))
```

In the second case it is impossible to accidentally "close" the window and drop all data.